# How to see Service bus queue messages in readable form?

Tags: azure, nservicebus, service-bus-explorer

I am new to Service Bus and Azure. My service bus has messages but data looks not readable. I am using Service Bus Explorer. Can you please guide how to see data in readable form?

Thanks

[image]

Comment: What kind of messages are put in the queue? At the moment the content type is set to a binary content, that will be of course hard to read.

Comment: @PeterBons thanks. these messages are coming from d365. Can I convert them to readable form ?\

Comment: my guess is these are xml

Comment: Does this post answer your question?

Answer (score 0):

In the following link at step "After connecting to the required instance, click on Register –> Register New Service Endpoint.", choose the message format as "JSON or XML " as suggested by people who have already seen this issue.

https://community.dynamics.com/365/b/ajitpatra365crm/archive/2018/09/26/azure-service-bus-queue-integration-with-d365-part-1

Reference from previous instance of this issue elsewhere
https://community.dynamics.com/crm/f/117/t/155942

https://community.dynamics.com/crm/f/117/t/155628

plugin registration tool when you register your service endpoint you MUST select either JSON or XML for Message Format.

use a 'queue' instead of 'persistentqueue' as the contract type in the Plugin registration tool while configuring the endpoint.

Comment: you can also try https://www.cogin.com/mq/download.php it gives a very rich feature set